# Extracting cell values from a range of dates in column names in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, filter

I'd like to extract data from a df in which I've got a column of dates of species observations (Date) and to the right of that column I've got temperature values for many dates. The col names for these temperatures are the dates in which temperatures were registered, in date format (ddmmyyy).

The data frame looks something like:

```
set.seed(0)

Sp <- data.frame(Site = c(seq(1:50)),
                 Date = c(seq(as.Date("2012/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 50)),
                 "01/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)),
                 "02/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)),
                 "03/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)),
                 "04/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)),
                 "05/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)),
                 "06/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)),
                 "07/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)),
                 "08/01/2012" = c(runif(n = 50, min = 20, max = 40)))
```

I would like to extract either as new columns or a new df,  the temperature for each sampling observation (column Date), 1 day before sampling Date and two days before the sampling Date, to new columns that would be named "T0", "T-1", "T-2". For example, on sampling date (column Date) 05/01/201, I'd like to get retrieve the temperature from column 05/01/2012 as "T0", then temperature from column 04/01/2012 as "T-1", and temperature from column 03/01/2012 as "T-2". I would also like keep the remaining columns such as Site and Date.

I've tried exploring some options using dplyr but haven't had much luck.

The expected output would be something like (these are just dummy numbers)

```
Site    Date       T0(2012-01-03)      T-1(2012-01-02)     T-2(2012-01-01)
 1   2012-01-03          21.5                20.8                20.5
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Date` increments daily, but the columns' dates do not, so I don't understand how one would get `T0`, `T-1`, and `T-2` temperatures for (say) `"2012-01-14"`. What is your expected output? Please add `set.seed(42)` (or some number) before you create the random data above, and provide your expected output (for at least some of it). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry if it wasn't clear enough, I've tried to give an idea of a time series of data as date columns, so the columns represent a day on each location and I've got years worth of data, so any observation registered on the "Date" column it has, for sure, the requested data range covered. Thanks

Comment: please provide expected output as a real frame

Comment: what have you tried? If anything? There's no code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround:

1. I had to extract the dates from my "Date" column manually

   ```
   Sp$Date <- as.character(Sp$Date) #This transforms date into character to allow operations

   Sp$Day_1<-(as.Date(Sp$Date)-1) # Obtains the previous day to the obserbation by substracting one day from registered date
   ```
2. Searching from temperature values based on the colnames and creating a new column named T0

   ```
   Sp$T0 <- Sp[cbind(1:nrow(Sp), match(Sp$Date, colnames(Sp)))] #Original day

   Sp$T1 <- Sp[cbind(1:nrow(Sp), match(Sp$Day_1, colnames(Sp)))] # Day (-1)
   ```

This does the trick. Takes a bit of coding but could be done on a loop for large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

Sp |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(Site, Date), names_to= "T0") |>
  mutate(T0 = str_remove(T0, "X") |> dmy(),
        `T-1` = T0 - days(1),
        `T-2` = T0 - days(2))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 400 × 6
    Site Date       T0         value `T-1`      `T-2`     
   <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <date>     <date>    
 1     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-01  23.8 2011-12-31 2011-12-30
 2     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-02  21.4 2012-01-01 2011-12-31
 3     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-03  35.0 2012-01-02 2012-01-01
 4     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-04  38.1 2012-01-03 2012-01-02
 5     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-05  27.8 2012-01-04 2012-01-03
 6     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-06  26.7 2012-01-05 2012-01-04
 7     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-07  39.1 2012-01-06 2012-01-05
 8     1 2012-01-01 2012-01-08  23.3 2012-01-07 2012-01-06
 9     2 2012-01-02 2012-01-01  26.8 2011-12-31 2011-12-30
10     2 2012-01-02 2012-01-02  22.5 2012-01-01 2011-12-31
# ℹ 390 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! this is very close to what I am looking for. I need the temperature values on days T-1 and days T-2 too, not only the dates. I'd need 2 other "value" columns, to the right of T-1 and T-2, respectively, indicating the temperature on those days. Alternatively, I'm not really bothered about getting the dates, as long as I have the original "Date" column then I could have "T0" (with a value of 23.8 as the first case) then "T-1" (displaying temperature value on 2011-12-31), then "T-2" (displaying temperature value on 2011-12-30). Thanks again!

Comment: Can you explain what the two dates actually correspond to? i.e. in your question, you say that the first date column 'Date' is the date of "species observations", and all the other columns with Dates in their names are temperature values on those dates.

Comment: What does (say) a Date value of 2012-02-12 and a X01.01.2012 value of 22.62833 mean?

Comment: I need to know the temperature on the day in which an observation was made ("Date") and up to 7 days before the observation day ("Date" -1, "Date" -2... and so on). X01.01.2012 means that on 01-01-2012 the temperature was 22.63 degrees. All these are dummy variables that I created keeping the structure of my actual data in which I have a column "Date", "Site" and many columns which headers are calendar days but their cell values are temperatures registered on that particular calendar date and site. Hope this helps

Comment: wait so in a Date value of 2012-02-12 and a X01.01.2012 value of 22.62833, what does the Date column value 2012-02-12 represent?

Comment: A biological observation on a particular "Date" when on that "Date" the temperature was xyz, noted on the column named X01.01.2012

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255141/discussion-between-rgr-288-and-mark).